# make: setting up a complex prerequisit list

Tags: c++, c, shell, makefile

I have problems writing a proper makefile target for my usecase.

I have a script which can generate header and source files. The input files for generating the header myHeader.h are config/myHeader.h.template and config/myHeader.xlsx.
As one can see, the input files are not in the same directory as the header needs to be, but in the "config" subdirectory.

In the makefile, I have a list, containg all the headers and sources which shall be generated by the script.

```
MY_GENERATED_HEADERS =  $(sort \
            foo/bar/myHeader1.h \
            foo/bar/myHeader2.h)
```

Further, I have a target which can be called from "outside":

```
generate: $(MY_GENERATED_HEADERS)
```

So when i write

```
make generate
```

on the command line, i want to check for each header in my list if its time to generate again.

So, now  the complicated part.
I have to write a target which finaly calls my script when a .h.template or .xlsx has changed.

```
$(MY_GENERATED_HEADERS): %.h: %.h.template %.xlsx
    @echo $@
    #invoke the script...
```

In the rules, I can set up the absolute file names which are needed to invoke my script. Thats no problem, jsut use some automatic variables and string manipulation functions.

The actual problem is the prerequisit list: In the above solution it is assumed that .h.template and .xlsx files are in the same directory as the output header (foo/bar/), however, I want them to be in foo/bar/config to clean up the filesystem a little bit.

In the above solution, I will get the error message

```
No rule to make target 'foo/bar/myHeader1.h.template'.
```

Yeah, sure thats right because myHeader1.h.template is in foo/bar/config...

I have added all directories to VPATH, but that doesn't change anything at all.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: try something like `$(MY_GENERATED_HEADERS): %.h: $(dir %)/config/$(notdir %).h.template $(dir %)/config/$(notdir %).xlsx`

Comment: Seems that $(dir %) return "." and $(notdir %) returns "foo/bar/myHeader1".
So, your solution throws the error:
No rule to make target 'config/foo/bar/myHeader1.h.template".
According to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html is this NOT the way dir and notdir should work.
Maybe they don't work in prerequisit lists?

Comment: I juste try my suggestion with file in ./, so I didn't see this. Thanks to Louis for the final corrected answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Garf365 [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3932569/garf365) cannot work unless you use [`.SECONDEXPANSION`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) to turn on the second expansion of dependencies. Here's a Makefile that illustrate how the solution could work:

```
# Some value for the sake of illustration.
MY_GENERATED_HEADERS=foo/bar/1.h foo/baz/2.h

all: $(MY_GENERATED_HEADERS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(MY_GENERATED_HEADERS): %.h: $$(dir %)config/$$(notdir %).h.template $$(dir %)config/$$(notdir %).xlsx
    @echo Target: $@
    @echo Dependencies: $^
```

I've tested the example before posting it here.

When you use `.SECONDEXPANSION` you have to be careful to have your variable and function calls expanded at the right time. The first expansion is done when the rule is first read *before* `%` acquires any value (same for the automatic variables). The second expansion is done when Make is about to apply a rule to a specific target: at that time, `%` has a value (so do the automatic variables). You use `$$` for things you want expanded at the time of the second expansion. At the time of the first expansion, the dependencies will be converted to:

```
$(dir %)config/$(notdir %).h.template $(dir %)config/$(notdir %).xlsx
```

Then at the time of the second expansion (which happens once per target) `%` will be replaced with its value and $(dir ...) and $(notdir ...) will be called.

Comment: Thanks a lot Louis! In the meanwhile, I have tested the other way around: create a list of .xlsx files and calculate the other file names from this list. I find it easier to list the "input files", which will be "compiled" to header files. However, this approach didn't work either. I tried to remove the /config/ part of the first prerequisite using patsubst, but didn't work. I guess i need to use SECONDEXPANSION there as well? Maybe you could give me a hint on that? However, your solution is fine as well, thank you again!